# Android Notification into Alert Notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcast, alarm

I built an notification which works so far.
Since I did not know that it works only inside of my application I read through some articles and saw that I need an 'Alarm Notification'.
I tried varous things but none did not work, now I am asking here.

My Notification in my Mainactivity looks like this:

```
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_01 = 1;

public void sendNotificationIfTimeEnd01() {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent01 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent01 = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent01, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder01 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent01)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle(gamesJuliToStringArray[0])
            .setContentText("Ready")
            .setSubText("click");
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
            NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_01, builder01.build());
    try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am accesing this notification in my Fragment if a specific conditions happens:

```
    final MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

       if (i = 10) {
            activity.sendNotificationIfTimeEnd01();
            editor.putBoolean("notification01", true);
            editor.apply();
        }
```

Again I want to transform this Notification into an 'Alarm' / 'Alarm Notification'.

I appreciate any response!